# what are the rules zig build-lib uses for shared objects filenames?

Tags: zig

I have a sqlite extension file. The source is `sqliteext/csv.c`. When I build the lib with clang the output file is created at `lib/csv.so`.

```
cc -g -fPIC -I /usr/local/include -shared sqliteext/csv.c -o lib/csv.so
```

When I compile the lib using zig...

```
zig build-lib -I /usr/local/include -I /usr/include -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --c-source sqliteext/csv.c -dynamic --output-dir lib
```

There are two problems.

- zig prefixes the filename with a `lib`
- zig add a version number thing in the suffix

so the output file is `lib/libcsv.so.0.0.0`

And what's interesting about this is that I need to change the filename in my extension loader (that's ok) but that I also need a symlink to handle the `0.0.0`.

I'm still looking at the CLI help but I'm still not seeing the thing I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/2230 and https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/2231

The former was fixed the same day as your post via https://github.com/ziglang/zig/pull/6315

Comment: I guess this is good enough to say that this is still under development. In my case they also added the 0.0.0 and that meant I needed to add a bare symlink